# How to make 360° renders for Virtual Reality devices (ie Oculus, etc) using Blender?

Tags: rendering, camera

I'm trying to figure out how to make 360-degree panoramic renders for virtual reality content? I'm trying to make the content to the specs of HoneyVR to submit something to their VR program but they are asking for the content in "equirectangular project" at 2:1 aspect ratio and I'm a bit loss.

I'm using Blender / Cycles but I can use other renderers too.  Any help or tutorials much appreciated!

Here is the link to the HoneyVR file specifications which shows the needed aspect ratios, resolutions, etc.  Is it possible with Blender?

http://www.honeyvr.com/content-specs/

Answer (score 8):

With Cycles you can set your Camera to Panoramic and Equirectangular

[image]

Make sure you have recent Blender builds. Also see the [Blender manual docs for Camera](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/camera.html)

Comment: Why does the preview tile at the top and bottom? That's misleading

Comment: @Random832 what's misleading about it?

Comment: Those edges aren't normally supposed to match up. They seem to, by coincidence, in your image, but normally e.g. one is the floor and the other's the ceiling. Tiling them in the preview could lead someone to believe that there's something wrong with the render when they don't match.

Comment: Hey thanks for the info Random832. Does anybody know if you can render the panos with Blender and V-ray or do you have to use Cycles?

Answer (score 4):

They also accept 3D-360° renders. For those you need a build from the spherical-stereo branch. I keep them updated in my site, until we have it officially in Blender: [ [link](http://www.dalaifelinto.com/?p=1009) ]