# 360 top bottom photo

Tags: rendering

[image]

Hello,

I created a scene and rendered it with panoramic- equirectangular camera. I chose 3d stereo- top-bottom view in view format. After rendered i got a photo like attached photo. my question is, is it possible to upload to facebook as a 360 photo and how to watch with vr headset? 
Thanks
Have a nice day.

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/74291/29586 - although not 3d. However, I don't think this is possibly in 3D for a single rendered image (it would have to render in realtime to change the viewpoint of both eyes as you turn your head).

Comment: You could render n number of frames even though nothing changes, youtube would then play the essentially static video but allow the user to change their perspective. Set n for the length you would want users to interact with the video.